# Should I be using a / or a \ in directory strings?

Tags: powershell

I have this script:

```
$appArray | foreach {
    $o = $_;
    Get-ChildItem .\app\$o\partials -Recurse | 
        ForEach-Object {
            $i = $_;
            Write-Host "app/$o/partials/$i";
            Write-S3Object `
                -BucketName "staging" `
                -Key  "app/$o/partials/$i" `
                -File "app/$o/partials/$i" `
                -HeaderCollection @{"Cache-Control" = "public,max-age=3600"}
        }
}
```

The script is in the directory below the `app` directory so I would like when doing `Get-ChildItem` to go up one directory and I would like "app/..." to start off by going up one directory.

Should I be using `/` or `\`, and how should I go up one directory for this command?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - fixed that.  Thanks I'd added by mistake as I was also working on a gulp file problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `/`. But to get the parent directory, you should consider using [GetParent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[System.IO.Directory]::GetParent('YOUR_PATH')
```

Or the [Split-Path](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849809.aspx) cmdlet:

```
Get-Item 'YOUR_PATH' | Split-Path -parent
```

Or access the property:

```
 (Get-Item 'YOUR_PATH').parent.fullname
```

And here your adopted code. Note: Im also using the [Join-Path](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113347) cmdlet to combine the path and determine the script directory in the first line (otherwise your script will only work if your current location is the script dir):

```
$scriptPath = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$scriptParentPath = $scriptPath | Split-Path -Parent

$appArray | foreach {
    $o = $_;
    $currentPath = Join-Path (Join-Path $scriptParentPath $o) 'partials'
    Get-ChildItem $currentPath -Recurse | 
        ForEach-Object {
            ...
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would apply this to the code I have in the question. Can I not just use a . or .. to go to an upper directory?

Comment: I Updated my answer. You can use `..` to go up an directory. But I prefer using the mentioned functions.

Comment: a better way, considering you will have a `[DirectoryInfo]` or `[FileInfo]` returned from `Get-ChildItem` is to use the `Directory` property of that object. This property is the Parent which already `-is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]`

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, since around 2003 both / and \ are valid path delimiters (even in CMD.exe)

Is there a reason for piping to `foreach-object` rather than using

```
foreach ($o in $appArray) {
    foreach ($i in (Get-ChildItem .\app\$o\partials -Recurse)) {
        <your code>
    }
}
```

I ask as within the pipline you are unable to use `continue`, `break` or 'exit' as it will affect the pipeline not the loop even in any nested loops.

And finally, to answer your comment above, you could use `.` and `..` but then you will have to build the path yourself rather than using `split-path -parent` and `join-path`. If you have a path or a [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] or [System.IO.FileInfo] (as returned by `Get-ChildItem`)why not simplify your code and use the builtin commands.

```
foreach ($folder in $appArray) {
    foreach ($item in (Get-ChildItem .\app\$folder\partials -Recurse)) {
        $itemPath = $item.Fullname -replace "$PWD\","" 
        Write-Host $itemPath
        Write-S3Object `
            -BucketName "staging" `
            -Key $itemPath
            -File $ItemPath
            -HeaderCollection @{"Cache-Control" = "public,max-age=3600"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `return` inside `%` pipeline instead of `continue`. You can't `break`.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use /.

Linux tools sometimes require it, and scripts will eventually be more portable when Posh on Linux becomes real.